# Reference an entire environment with its content

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, compiling, include

I have `big-book.tex` containing many exercises in `\begin{problem}` environments, and I want to make a `homework.tex` for students selecting only a few of them.

Here are some methods I can think of:

1. Copy-paste: problem is that I have to keep both in sync, and goes against DRY principle.
2. Create separate `problem-no238.tex` then `\include` it in both `big-book.tex` and `homework`. Problem is that it's impractical for writing a book with many exercises.
3. Shell script to fetch references: This could be the closest to a solution, but I thought having a native LaTeX commands to do this would be more efficient and cleaner.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the code for your `problem` environment or a dummy code at least with a compilable document and then ask what you want to have.

Comment: As far as I understand it, you want to extract all the instances of `problem` environment and print them without any other content, right?

Comment: Not all, but only some selections.

Comment: You can store them in a separate file and import individual environments from there using the [catchfilebetweentags](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/catchfilebetweentags/catchfilebetweentags.pdf) package. Or use one of the [many exercise packages](https://ctan.org/topic/exercise) that also provide exercise database functionalities.